# Change Individual Post Link URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling with this one - I'm sure there's a plugin that can achieve this, however I'm looking to achieve it - plugin-free as I don't want to bloat my WP with plugins - particularly for something that is a one off.

I want to change the URL of individual post to something that is outside the theme but hosted on the same domain. The idea is that I want to customise the content of that individual post to whatever I like.

EDIT - There seems to be a little confusion here.

MY usual url structure for posts is like this:
www.mysite.com/year/month/post-title

I want to change one single post to

www.mysite.com/unthemed-post

The important thing is not just the url itself but what it points to. I want the url to point to content outside the WP theme. I can't change it in the WP settings as my permalink structure already uses the Year/Month format.

I suppose I could just post it regulary and use a HTACCESS redirect to redirect it like this:

www.mysite.com/year/month/post-title to www.mysite.com/unthemed-post

However I'm not sure that it's the best solution.

Thanks

Comment: why not change the individual permalinks of the post? did you tried that out?

Comment: When you say "outside the theme", do you mean you want to display content on a certain posts differently than for the other posts in that theme? And what exactly do you mean by "customize the content"? If you're just looking to change the ways the URL is displayed for certain posts, [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) might help.

Comment: I mean I don't want any of the theme's back-end included in the post - so an individual link directs outside the theme.

Comment: I suppose I could use a HTACCESS redirect to redirect an individual post no?

Comment: As @rockStar said, why don't you try with changing the individual permalinks of the post.?

Comment: I can't able to understand your problem clearly. Can you please give an example how the url is displaying currently? For example www.domainname.com/sea/fishing/fishingtypes

Comment: Because if I change the post permalink in WP post edit, the url is still within the database and WP-theme.

Comment: Let us try the following. Go to WordPress Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks, there change the file structure as you want. Then you can have your desired URL style.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the post or page.
2. Above the content, where it says “Permalink,” click the “Edit” button.
3. Type in your new permalink.
4. Hit enter.